# Twitter and salesforce integration

Tags: integration

I have to do integration between salesforce and twitter so that we can bring and store tweets in salesforce.I have done some research but I am not able to decide from where to start.Can somebody just outline the steps in sequence which I should follow in order to accomplish it.I know that Oauth has to be implemented and I am already trying to understand it  and then some Tweeter APi has to be used.From where can I get the tweeter API and which API will allow me to establish connection.Can somebody provide right link for it.If somebody can help me with this then at least I can start from somewhere.

Comment: Can you detail what you've tried so far? Also have you checked out the AppExchange? There are a few existing solutions for things kind of thing I believe.

Answer (score 5):

I wrote a blog post about how to setup the authentication with Twitter from Salesforce - in my example I use it to retrieve some basic stats about Contacts with a twitter handle, but you can use it to any actions with the Twitter 1.1 API once you have authenticated it.

http://www.bridgefarmconsulting.com/blog/twitter-authentication/

Answer (score 5):

I had my share of headache trying to implement this integration. It sounds so easy but twitter documentation is tricky for a newbie. 
Anyway, answer by @BritishBoyinDC should get you started in the api implementation, i'll just add a few more points to it.

First read and go through OAuth Signing document (oauth.net/core/1.0/#signing_process). It helped a lot.

Second when using twitter there are a couple of ways to do the authentication and obtain the access code (dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/obtaining-access-tokens), go through this.

Third implement your method. I choose the 'sign in with twitter' use case (dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/implementing-sign-twitter), an advise the documentation is a bit tricky so don't fret if you think you are doing it great but still you have your set of issue.

Fourth and most important, check your signature method as you can easily mess up with it and get a Bad Authentication Code response from twitter. Check the documentation here, dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/creating-signature .

Fifth, don't forget to add twitter api endpoints in your remote site settings.

and once the authentication is done, you are all set to use the apis.

For reference on authentication you can use this code (https://code.google.com/p/apex-twitter-api/), though you'll be required to do a lot of modification for your integration.
Also check out the JSON parsing(as twitter uses only JSON now),  the code in @BritishBoyinDC 's blog should help you out here. 
Last but not the least, there is no guarantee about twitter changing/modifying it's endpoints or return format so keep yourself updated.

Answer (score 3):

This should help you get started.

http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Getting_Started_with_TwitterForce